on the Thompson sampling proof
I was reading recently the Thompson sampling paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.4217. The non-constant (w.r.t $T$) leading term of the regret is obtained (begining of page 5) by bounding $\sum_{t=1}^T\mathbb{P}[\theta_{a,t}>\mu_1 - \sqrt{\frac{6\log(t)}{N_{1,t}}}, A_t=a]$. However, I am getting confused about some way I found to bound this term by a constant. There should be something I am not doing right, but I can't figure it out... can somebody help me?
Let $0<\epsilon<(\mu_1-\mu_a)/2$. From  Proposition 1, we can assume that $N_{1,t}\geq t^b$. Assuming that $t$ is greater than some constant $C(\epsilon)$, we have $\sqrt{\frac{6\log(t)}{N_{1,t}}}\leq \epsilon$. We can also asume that $\hat\mu_{a,t}\leq \mu_a+\epsilon$ :
$$\sum_{t=1}^T\mathbb{P}[\hat\mu_{a,t}\geq \mu_a+\epsilon,A_t=a] \leq 1+\sum_{w=1}^T\mathbb{P}[\hat\mu_{a,t}\geq \mu_a+\epsilon,N_{a,t}=w]\leq 1+\epsilon^{-2}.$$
Thus, the leading term should be captured by $\sum_{t\geq C(\epsilon)}^T \mathbb{P}[\theta_{a,t}>\mu_1-\mu_a - 2\epsilon +\hat\mu_{a,t}, A_t=a]$. Looking a the conditional probability on $\theta_{a,t}$, we get a bound aqual to
$$\mathbb{E}[\sum_{t}e^{-0.5N_{a,t}(\mu_1-\mu_a - 2\epsilon)^2}\mathbb{I}(A_t=a)]\leq 1+\mathbb{E}[\sum_{w}e^{-0.5w(\mu_1-\mu_a - 2\epsilon)^2}\mathbb{I}(N_{a,t}=w)]\leq cst.$$
